# How to make u shape stair?

Tags: modifiers, add-on

Is there any simple way to create

[image] and modify U shape stair

Looking for this type of Stairs (https://youtu.be/picUg5ukuPk?t=318)

The stair should have Landing and from ground floor to 1st floor it should go. The height from the ground floor to 1st floor is 10 feet height, width 5 feet. So how it will work, any addon or modifier can make it, and later i can adjust it. Thx

Comment: THere's a tutorial using Geometry nodes [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PkdI87qDho) with a downloadable chargeable (3 Euros+) node tree [here](https://blenderbash.gumroad.com/l/tRVbM). You'll have to model the landing yourself though!

Comment: Hey atek :). What have you tried so far yourself? This is fairly simple to model manually.

Comment: @jachymmichal, I tried with the array, but when comes to landing, i can't fix it. Yes, geometry nodes are good but I never understood those nodes. If the height is 10 feet how many stairs and landing will fit?

Comment: The landing is just simple modelling. Do each flight of stairs seperately with the 'floor' of the lower one starting at ground level and the landing being the 'floor' level for the upper flight. The number of steps will depend on the thickness of each step and the height of the flight and will be handled by that geometry node video.

Comment: Try the Archipack or Archimesh addons, they have builtin stair generators